# Assigning values of points inside buffer to origin of buffer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, select-by-location, spatial-analysis

I have created a map with several bike routes. At each bike ride we have collected meteorological data and now I want to analyze and compare the collected data. My problem is that the GPS tracker wasn't that accurate and now the different rides wont have the same coordinates.

[image]

I created a standard route (red), and I had the idea I could "just" assign the values of the (green) points near by...., but I couldn't.

Is there an easy way to do that?

I tried it with buffer, but it wont work.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are talking about is a spatial join. You could try either 'Join attributes by location' or Join attributes by nearest' in the processing toolbox.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you edit your question and add some more details about the logic you'd like to use to snap the 'bad' points to the other GPS points, or the road (which is what I suspect you really need)? Also sharing the steps you've tried, and where it failed, will help to get you answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute a new column for the red point-layer with the field calculator and the very powerful aggregate function. The expression should something like the following one:

```
aggregate(layer:='points_green',
aggregate:='mean',
expression:="valuecol_from_points_green",
filter:=intersects(buffer($geometry,30), geometry(@parent)),
)
```

this will compute for each point in red the mean-value from column "valuecol_from_points_green" for all points in points_green which are in a distance of 30 meters. you should play around with the distance and the aggregate-function. You can use max, min, median instead, see also: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#aggregates-functions

If you value is not numeric, you can use the concatenate operator instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
I tried it with join by nearest and it worked!!
I will also try this solution, it seems more accurate to calculate the mean values instantly. 
 :) Thanks for the fast response.